# What do I need to do to publish my app in the Microsoft Store after associating it?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, publishing, windows-store

I am trying to pubish my Winforms app to the Microsoft Store. My solution uses a Packaging project, and I selected "Publish" from the Packaging App in Visual Studio 2019.

I first selected item #1 in the screenshot below and went through the steps there (selecting the "Finish" button, which gave no feedback); then I selected item #2. There were also no messages after associating my app with the Store (either that it failed or not).

[image]

So I searched the Microsoft Store for my app, and it was not there...

What do I need yet to do, or what did I do wrong? What is the next step after associating my app to actually upload it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question about an app store procedure, not about programming.

Answer (score 0):

By looking through screenshots I'd taken of a previous Microsoft Store submission, I was able to see that you must go here to submit your app:

```
https://partner.microsoft.com/en-us/dashboard/products/
```

...to submit an app; but from where do you reach this otherwise (if you don't already have the URL squirreled away somewhere)? It's odd that the submission page is hidden or at least so hard to find. Does MS actively discourage uploads of apps by making the process difficult?

It seems to me there should be an Upload option right from the Microsoft Store that would lead you to this page.